# How do I convince a supervisor who's afraid of/new to repository environments?

Tags: version-control

I've almost convinced the place I'm co-oping (aka I'm only short-term) at to start using version control. Right now they (small shop setting) are copy-pasting their projects to a drive on the network once they update it (yikes!). After teaching about Git and having them play around with it, the **ONE** concern I have to resolve is: *"Let's say Git is magically no longer a thing and all our local versions have been deleted. What then?"* This is in response to the fact that the remote repository is a bare repository. I've determined what the problem really is is that he doesn't feel comfortable with a repo environment due to it being a new concept to him.

**How do I convince someone who is interested in Version Control (Git), but afraid to transition to a repo environment?**

Comment: Ended up making a separate "Pull Only" set of directories to easy their concerns. I think next step is to improve the release of in-house programs lol.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Git Parabel will help you to convince?

http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html

Also there is a very nice book, but it's german only.
It's called "Daily Git. Wie ein kompetenter Kollege Ihnen Git erklären würde." (How a competent colleague would explain Git to you) by Martin Dilger.